# debugging js scripts

Tags: wp-enqueue-script

I am having problems enqueuing javascript. When I use the script tag in the head section of my site, everything works just fine. If I take the scripts out and use enqueue, the site breaks but I don't get any errors in firebug. Viewing the source code, the entire page looks as if it is there but obviously some of the js scripts are not working and this causes my site to crash. Is there a way to find out why it's crashing? The console has nothing in it.

I would link to the site but I am going to continue working and since things will change, the link won't be much good. I am looking for tips to debugging js errors. Where can I look?

my method of enqueueing the script

```
 wp_register_script('isotope', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/jquery.isotope.min.js',array('jquery'),'',true);

 wp_enqueue_script('isotope');


 function bliss_jsscripts(){
   if( !is_admin()){
    wp_register_script('supersized', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/supersized.3.2.6.js',array('jquery'), false, true);

    wp_enqueue_script('supersized','','',false,'');

    }
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'bliss_jsscripts', 999);
```

Comment: Could you add the script tag that you are using in the head section to enqueue the same script? Have you enabled `WP_DEBUG`, and do you receive any PHP/WordPress error messages? Have you tried registering the script to print in the header instead of the footer (by setting the last argument of `wp_register_script()` to `false` instead of `true`)? I'd also recommend setting the `$version` argument to `false` rather than an empty string `''` while debugging this issue. Are you properly calling `wp_enqueue_script()` within a hook attached to the `wp_enqueue_scripts` action? In what file is this?

Comment: Thanks for the comments. I am working on your suggestions. I added to my question above to show more. I have tried setting the version to false in both the register and enqueue; however, the version is still there in the source code. I am calling everything from the functions.js file, wp_debug is set to true. I do not get any php errors. I have got some in firebug now and I think it might be related to the dreaded document.ready(function stuff. I have tried many different ways of wrapping these functions to get them to work

Comment: why would I get a bunch of errors saying TypeError: $ is not a function when using enqueue but I don't get any of that when using a script tag. I just don't understand why putting a script in the header works just fine yet using enqueue to do the same thing causes type errors.

Comment: Your code as it's written isn't attempting to do "the same thing" as a script tag in the header - when you're using `wp_register_script()` you're passing arguments to print your script in the footer - not the header - for starters. Additionally, when you call `wp_enqueue_script()` with all those empty strings, you're over-writing many of the arguments that you set in `wp_register_script()`... I recommend spending some time reviewing the Codex entries for these two functions before we troubleshoot this further.

Comment: For simplicity sake, let's just cut out the `wp_register_script()` entirely and use `wp_enqueue_script()` alone - it will register the script itself if it sees it's not already registered. Additionally, you shouldn't have any calls to `wp_enqueue_script()` outside of a function hooked to the `'wp_enqueue_scripts'` action - the Codex mentions all of this, don't be afraid to dig ;) . It would also still be helpful if you could share the properly functioning script tag that you are attempting to reproduce with WordPress functions.

Comment: Additionally, if you are developing or modifying a theme this code should be in a `functions.php` file - _not_ `functions.js`

Answer (score 2):

What you might do is check the status of the scripts you are trying to enqueue after doing so.

Also, be sure to enqueue things inside of an action.

e.g.

```
function do_my_enqueue_scripts() {
   wp_register_script('isotope', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/jquery.isotope.min.js',array('jquery'),'',true);

   wp_enqueue_script('isotope');
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'do_my_enqueue_scripts');
```

You can use the [wp_script_is](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_script_is) function to check if they actually get enqueued.

e.g. after

```
wp_enqueue_script('isotope');
if ( ! wp_script_is('isotope', 'enqueued') ) {
    echo '<p>Script failed to queue up!</p>';
}
```

Comment: I will try the wp_script_is function to see if all of them are working. I do believe they are all enqueued. I counted.

Comment: My issue seems to have resolved itself. I added some versions to the scripts rather than leaving it blank and that seems to have gotten them working.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem likely stems from using the WordPress functions incorrectly - there is probably no need to debug any Javascript to solve the issue. Carefully review [the Codex entry for `wp_enqueue_script()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script).

I assume this is what you are attempting to accomplish. In your theme's **functions.php** file:

```
function wpse178370_enqueue_scripts() {
    wp_enqueue_script( 'isotope', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/jquery.isotope.min.js', array('jquery') );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'supersized', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/supersized.3.2.6.js', array('jquery'), '3.2.6' );
}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'wpse178370_enqueue_scripts' );
```

Unless you're enquing a script at largely different points in your code, or swapping out script registrations on the fly, there's not too much of a reason to use `wp_register_script()` at all. Likewise, unless you explicitly need a script to be printed in the site footer (at `wp_footer()`) *instead of* within the `<head></head>` tags, you shouldn't be setting the `$in_footer` argument of `wp_enqueue_script()`/`wp_register_script()` to `true`.

If you register a script using `wp_register_script()` and specify all those optional arguments, then call `wp_enqueue_script()` with the same script tag and again specify all those optional arguments, you will override the arguments that you specified in `wp_register_script()`.

Additionally, the `is_admin()` conditional check is uneccessary as dashboard scripts are printed on the `'admin_enqueue_scripts'` action, not `'wp_enqueue_scripts'`.

Comment: I am going to take things back to the beginning to when they were working with the script tags in the header. Then I will fix things up the way you suggested by only using the wp_enqueue_function and then I will edit my post above. Give me some time to make that change. Thank you for your comments. I have found them to be helpful.